# Warning: Data for foo has hit the 0.0323 GB daily cap and the collection of your app's telemetry data will be stopped until June 23, 2018 9:00 AM UTC

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I've been getting these alerts lately, however if I search events in my Application Insights account, I only have 5 events in the last 24 hours, and 7 events in the last 48 hours. The largest event contains a 660 characters long message. I doubt these events are close to 33 MB, which is equivalent to 0.0323 GB, right?

[image: warning email]

[image: search panel]

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

I found the Application Insights Analytics tool:

[image]

In the Analytics page, I noticed not all the tables were included in the query. Once I included the missing tables, I realized that 29,430 performanceCounter events and 88,290 customMetric events have been created in the last 48 hours.

Query:

```
union (traces
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-06-22T07:40:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-06-24T07:41:00.001Z)), (customEvents
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-06-22T07:40:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-06-24T07:41:00.001Z)), (pageViews
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-06-22T07:40:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-06-24T07:41:00.001Z)), (requests
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-06-22T07:40:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-06-24T07:41:00.001Z)), (dependencies
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-06-22T07:40:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-06-24T07:41:00.001Z)), (availabilityResults
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-06-22T07:40:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-06-24T07:41:00.001Z)), (exceptions
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-06-22T07:40:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-06-24T07:41:00.001Z)), (customMetrics
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-06-22T07:40:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-06-24T07:41:00.001Z)), (performanceCounters
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-06-22T07:40:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-06-24T07:41:00.001Z)), (browserTimings
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-06-22T07:40:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-06-24T07:41:00.001Z))
//| top 101 by timestamp desc
| summarize count() by itemType
```

Results:

```
itemType             count_
performanceCounter   29,430 
request              2  
customMetric         88,290 
trace                5
```

I guess this explains the alert I've been receiving.